# Symfony FOSUser. How to union changePassword and changeUsername forms

Tags: php, symfony

I use FOSUser bundle to perform user operations. Now I want to do single form which will have related to password and to email fields. I found ChangePassword and Username forms which already ready to use, but how to unite them? Should I make my own custom form? And if there are exists ready solution in FOS for resetting email (I mean need to change mail only after accepting). Of course I can do all of this with my own, but how to be better, I guess these actions already exists in the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forms in forms. But this is slow. It's an easier solution to make your own form. Fosuser does not provide an interface for every process. You have to expand according to your own needs. We recommend keeping the password change page separate. The Bcrypt encryption library slows down the page if it is slow.